# Dump std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> content to file

Tags: c++

To debug [nncase](https://github.com/kendryte/nncase) and see it in action i like to dump the variable `main_men_` declared [here](https://github.com/kendryte/nncase/blob/master/src/runtime/interpreter.cpp#L33)
like:

```cpp
main_mem_.reset(new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[model_header_->main_mem]);
```

to be dumped into a file each time we cross [here](https://github.com/kendryte/nncase/blob/f80013510b94361ee96c45ceaf09207070dec5b8/src/runtime/interpreter.cpp#L124).

I see they access the object [here](https://github.com/kendryte/nncase/blob/f80013510b94361ee96c45ceaf09207070dec5b8/src/runtime/interpreter.cpp#L156)
like:

```cpp
base = (uintptr_t)main_mem_.get();
```

I tried to dump the content with those lines:

```cpp
            std::ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open("infer-dbg/" + std::to_string(node_id) + " " + node_opcode_names(header.opcode).data());
            for(int i = 0; i < model_header_->main_mem*8; i++ )
            {

               myfile << *((uint8_t*)main_mem_.get()+i);
            }
            opCount++;
            myfile.close();
```

but that gives me always the same file, and i see the mem is changed.

How does a ideomatic C++ way to dump that variable could look like?

Comment: Why arent you using `std::vector<uint8_t>`? That's practically a `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` with a lot of extras

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but what is the reason for using `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` instead of `std::vector<uint8_t>` or possibly even plain `std::string`?

Comment: If `main_mem_` is pointing to `model_header_->main_mem` bytes of memory, why do you loop `model_header_->main_mem * 8` times? That will go way out of bounds of the allocated memory.

Comment: Your're right. *8 is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want is [std::basic_ostream::write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(main_mem_.get()), model_header_->main_mem);
```

Comment: That multiplication with `8`  doesn't seem quite correct. The `write` function takes a number of *bytes* as size, and as each "element" is a byte `main_mem` is enough.

Comment: It could be, I copied the number from his loop. I'll fix.

Comment: Using that cast gives an error with:
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::unique_ptr<unsigned char []>::pointer’ {aka ‘unsigned char*’} to type ‘const char*’
             myfile.write(static_cast<const char*>(main_mem_.get()), model_header_->main_mem);

Comment: then use `reinterpret_cast`, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are using a `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`, so I'll give an answer using the IMHO better alternative `std::vector<uint8_t>`. Or even more general

```cpp
template<typename T>
void Tofile(std::string_view fileName, std::vector<T> const& vec) {
   std::ofstream fs(fileName);
   if (!fs) throw std::exception("filestream is not available for some reason");
   std::copy(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), std::ostream_iterator<T>(fs));
}
```